# Is there a way to solve the error unable to find CDP implementation matching 117?

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm using selenium version 4.12.1 and webdriver 5.5.3
I have used maven-assembly-plugin to generate the jar.

When I used intelliJ to execute the project, I get no errors, but when I use the jar file , I get the following error:

Running by JAR:

> 2023-10-02 10:32.37 [main] INFO  i.g.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager -
> Using chromedriver 117.0.5938.92 (resolved driver for Chrome 117)
>
> 2023-10-02 10:32.37 [main] INFO  i.g.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager -
> Exporting webdriver.chrome.driver as
> C:\Users\grajkomar.cache\selenium\chromedriver\win64\117.0.5938.92\chromedr
>
> Oct 02, 2023 10:32:39 AM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder
> findNearestMatch
>
> WARNING: Unable to find CDP implementation matching 117
>
> Oct 02, 2023 10:32:39 AM org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver
> lambda$new$5
>
> WARNING: Unable to find version of CDP to use for 117.0.5938.132. You
> may need to include a dependency on a specific version of the CDP
> using something similar to
> `org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-devtools-v86:4.12.1` where the
> version ("v86") matches the version of the chromium-based browser
> you're using and the version number of the artifact is the same as
> Selenium's.

I have added selenium-devtools-v116 as dependency in my pom.xml but even this does not solve the error

By intelliJ:

> Oct 02, 2023 11:21:48 AM
> org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
> WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 117, so
> returning the closest version found: 116

By intelliJ, atleast it is returning version 116 but why for the jar one it is not returning the version 116?